# ExactTarget URLENCODE for "+" sign

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have some of records where emails have "+" sign in them, which throw an error when someone tries to Unsubscribe. Here is the partial code snippet that we are using for Unsub (Preference center).

```
SET @landingpage = 'http://pages.insurance.plymouthrock.com/page.aspx?QS=1cb10'

    IF @optout == "Yes" THEN
        SET @URL = CONCAT(@landingpage, '&email=', @email,'&policynum=', @policynum, '&recordtype=', @recordtype, '&company=', @company, '&corporation=', @corporation, '&policytype=', @policytype, '&update=optout')
    ELSE
        SET @URL = CONCAT(@landingpage, '&email=', @email,'&policynum=', @policynum, '&recordtype=', @recordtype, '&company=', @company, '&corporation=', @corporation, '&policytype=', @policytype, '&update=true') 
    ENDIF

    %%=Redirect(@URL)=%%
```

I believe I have to use URLENCODE function but it's not working. I tried different variations; but none of them works.

For example;

```
SET @URL = CONCAT(@landingpage, '&email=', URLEncode(@email),'&policynum=', @policynum, '&recordtype=', @recordtype, '&company=', @company, '&corporation=', @corporation, '&policytype=', @policytype, '&update=optout')


SET @URL = CONCAT(@landingpage, '&email=', URLEncode(@email,0,1),'&policynum=', @policynum, '&recordtype=', @recordtype, '&company=', @company, '&corporation=', @corporation, '&policytype=', @policytype, '&update=optout')

%%=Redirect(URLEncode(@URL))=%%
```

Can anyone guide me; where I am mistaken?

Comment: Anyone Please?????

Comment: Any Suggestion???? So far 20 views and no suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation actually helps out:

[Ampscript URLEncode function documentation](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/http/URLEncode.html)

You'll notice that the function call has two optional parameters 'illegals' and 'values' that when are left out or set to 0 only url encode space characters so you have to set them to 1 for other characters to get url encoded.

So this should work:

%%=Redirect(URLEncode(@URL,1,1))=%%